# How to create a new window when I click a button in QT?

Tags: qt

I want to create a new window and display a QImage in it.

```
void Demo::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    //create and show new window that displays a QImage
}
```

is it possible to use a QPixmap inside the new window to display my QImage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way.

```
QLabel *l = new QLabel;
l->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(QImage("path")));
l->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);
l->show();
```

If you use `QImage` then you should first of all convert it to `QPixmap`. `QPixmap` has special static method to do this: `fromImage`.

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qpixmap.html#fromImage

Also I used here `Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose`. What is it? It is special attribute and with this attribute `Qt` will automatically delete label when someone close it. We need this because we don't set parent to `QLabel` so we can get memory leak, but with this attribute all will be fine.
You can also `setGeometry()` of label by yourself.